# How to read xml stream using c#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am getting xml stream from client application how to parse that stream directly and how to load it to dataset?

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateFile/{id}", Method = "POST")]
       public bool UpdateTestXMLFile(string id, Stream createdText)
       {
 string filenamewithpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/files/" + id+".xml");
               System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filenamewithpath, Util.ReadFully(createdText));
}
```

Please tell me ..

Comment: `myDataSet.ReadXml(yourPath);` are you asking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**DataSet.ReadXml(Stream stream)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55hehd8c.aspx), overloaded method of data set, it takes stream in parameter.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UpdateFile/{id}", Method = "POST")]
public bool UpdateTestXMLFile(string id, Stream createdText)
{
   DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
   ds.ReadXml(createdText)

   string filenamewithpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/files/" + id+".xml");
   ds.WriteXml(filenamewithpath);      
}
```

Comment: i wrote dataset.ReadXml(createdText).Here createdText is xml stream then we can't load that data to dataset.

Comment: Are you still facing some problem?

Comment: Thanks getting result when passing ds.WriteXml(filenamewithpath);